# Added text not displaying in React native Todo application

Tags: css, react-native, react-hooks

am new in react native and am trying to create a small todo application , but when am trying to add text only style component i.e box displayed, but text is not displaying, why?  if you have any question please free feel to ask any time.

> in Below image i added text but text will not displaying only box will displayed

[image: added text not displayed]

> This are the my whole react native code.

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';
import Header from './Components/Header';

const App = () => {

  const [text, setText] = React.useState("");
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([])


  const addTodo = () => {
    if (text == "") {
      alert("Please Enter Todo");
    }
    else {
      setItems([...items, text]);
      setText('');
    }
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Header />
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        value={text}
        onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
      />
      <Button title="Add +"
        onPress={addTodo}
      />
      <View style={styles.list}>
        {
          items.map((elem, ind) => {
            return (
              <View key={ind}>
                <Text style={styles.item}>{elem}</Text>
              </View>
            )
          })
        }
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

export default App

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  list: {
    marginTop: 20,
    padding: 100,
  },
  item: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    padding: 20,
    marginTop: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderStyle: 'dashed',
    borderColor: 'gray',
    textAlign: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'lightgray',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'black',
    fontSize: 20
  },
  input: {
    height: 40,
    margin: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
  },
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```html
<TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        value={text}
        onChangeText={(t) => setText(t)}
      />
```

```html
<View style={styles.list}>
        {items.map((elem, ind) => <View key={ind}>
                <Text style={styles.item}>{elem}</Text>
              </View>)}
      </View>
```